# android activity is not destroyed on calling of finish()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to android development need some help with killing an activity

My finish() is not killing this activity whenever I start the new activity "survey_question" from my main activty for new survey my counter for yes and no doesnot go to zero

```
public class survey_question extends Activity {
int flag=0;
private static int yes=0,no=0;
TextView tv;
Button btnNext;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1,rb2;
String [] question;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey_question);

    tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_textview);

    rg= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.yesno_RadioGroup);
    rb1= (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.yes_RadioButton);
    rb2= (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.no_RadioButton2);
    question=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_question);
    tv.setText(question[flag]);





}
public void nextbutton (View v){
    RadioButton uans= (RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    String ansText= uans.getText().toString();
    if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
        yes++;

    }
    else{
        no++;
    }
    flag++;
    if (flag<question.length){
        tv.setText(question[flag]);

    }
    else{

        Intent resultIntent =new Intent(survey_question.this,main_survey.class);

        resultIntent.putExtra("yesans", yes);

        resultIntent.putExtra("noans", no);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        this.finish();


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared this variables like static fields:

```
private static int yes=0,no=0;
```

Change them to non static.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are not setting the values to zero.

You have declared `yes` and `no` to be `static`. They will retain their values for the life of the *process*, not the life of the *activity*.